# Explicit large finite fields in characteristic $2$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, sequences-and-series, finite-fields, characteristic-p

Every finite field of characteristic $2$ ist given by $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/P(x)$ for some irreducible polynomial $P\in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

For small degree, a simple algorithm gives a way to find $P$. Is there a way to give explicitely the polynomial $P$ for large degrees? I would be interested in a formula like
$$x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1 x+a_0$$
where $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}\in \mathbb{F}_2[n]$. This might be too much to ask for all degrees, so an infinite sequence of irreducible polynomials would be good.

EDIT: Some sequences have already be given. If you have more to share (with the proof of the irreducibility, either by giving the reference or explaining it), please go ahead.

Comment: I doubt that there is anything explicit working for all degrees, but an example of infinite sequence of irreducible polynomials is $x^{2\cdot 3^k}+x^{3^k}+1$

Comment: @AntoineLabelle It is a nice sequence. Could you make it as an answer and give either a reference or a proof on the fact that it is irreducible?

Comment: @YCor You added the tag "computer-algebra", that I removed because my question is more related to infinite sequences, and not finite sequences, which can be found with the computer.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc OK I see, sounds more like fitting [tag:sequence-and-series] then. (You also might want to fix $X$ vs $x$ in the displayed formula.)

Comment: @YCor Thanks I changed it.

Comment: Just to clarify the dependence on $n$ ("$\dots a_{n-1}\in F_2[n]$" sounds confusing), you're asking an infinite sequence of polynomials $(a_i(y))_{i\ge 0}$ such that for infinitely many $n$ (ideally all $n$), $x^n+a_{n-1}(n)x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1(n)x+a_0(n)$ is irreducible?

Comment: ... and by the way every polynomial function on $\mathbf{F}_2$ has degree $\le 1$ (i.e., can be represented by a polynomial of degree 1).

Comment: See also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70127/11619) in Math.SE. I quite like David E. Speyer's contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n=3^k$, the polynomial $p=x^{2n}+x^n+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

**Proof:** By Rabin's irreducibilty test, it suffices to check that $p|x^{2^{2n}}-x$ and $\gcd(p,x^{2^{2n/3}}-x)=1$.

Note that the order of $x$ mod $p$ is $3n=3^{k+1}$. Hence, since $3^{k+1}|4^{n}-1$ by lifting-the-exponent lemma, we have $p|x^{2^{2n}-1}-1$.

Again by lifting-the-exponent lemma, we have $4^{3^{k-1}}-1=3^km$ for $m$ not divisible by $3$. Hence $x^{4^{3^{k-1}}-1}=x^{nm}\equiv x^n\  \text{or}\ x^{2n} \pmod{p}$ since $x^n$ has order $3$. As $(x^n-1)x^n=(x^{2n}-1)x^{2n}=1$, this mean that $x^{2^{2n/3}-1}-1$ is invertible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(p)$. As $x$ is also invertible, we have shown that $\gcd(p,x^{2^{2n/3}}-x)=1$, as wanted.

Comment: nice, thanks for the proof.

Comment: Basically you need that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $3^{k+1}$. Many ways to see that.

Answer (score 7):

The following paper provides an explicit computational approach to your problem:

J. D. Swift: [**Construction of Galois fields of characteristic two and irreducible polynomials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2003204), *Math. Comput.* **14**, 99-103 (1960). [ZBL0105.01202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0105.01202).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I had seen some of these already, and I guess that with the current computers one can go quite far and find all irreducible polynomials of degree $\le d$ for some large $d$.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question!

The case of self-reciprocal irreducible trinomials and pentanomials is of interest in cryptography.

The linked paper  which I was not aware of before your question has the following result, see [here](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2005/cacr2005-06.pdf)

$$x^{3^s10}+x^{3^s9} +x^{3^s5}+x^{3^s}+1$$is a self-reciprocal irreducible pentanomial of degree $3^s10≡ 6 \pmod{12}$ for every positive integer $s$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a nice sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for all $k\geq 1$, $X^{2^k}+X+1\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is irreducible (even if I cannot put my finger on the right argument for the moment).

Comment: This looks like a nice formula. It would be good to have some proof of this.

Comment: @GreginGre Take a look at my proof for $x^{2\cdot 3^k}+x^{3^k}+1$, I think a similar method could work for this case.

Comment: You polynomial is reducible. Indeed, for any root $a$ of this polynomial in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$, you have $a^{2^{2r}} = (a^{2^r})^{2^r} = (a+1)^{2^r} = a$, so $a$ is in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2r}}$. If the polynomial were irreducible, it would generate the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^r}}$, which is bigger.

Comment: Strange. My favorite CAS says it is irreducible for $k=1,....,11$.

Comment: @GreginGre For $k = 3$, there is even a factorisation over $\mathbb{Z}$: $X^8+X+1 = (X^2+X+1)(X^6-X^5+X^3-X^2+1)$.

Comment: GreginGre [This Math.SE answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581159/11619) describes the factorization of your polynomial. The argument by @JérômePoineau is also outlined [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619). Anyway, this polynomial is reducible for all $k>2$.